# If No Tweets Are Selected Don't Send Email

Tags: node.js, email, heroku, twitter

Been working on this application www.prhunters.com It scans Twitter and pulls out tweets that contain certain keywords.

The code below governs the Daily Summary email which is sent out once a day. However, some days when there are no matches the email is empty.

**How can I customise the code below to only send when there are tweets and not send when the email would be empty?**

Thanks for your help!

```
export function sendDailyTweets({notifications}){
console.log('send daily tweets');
let promises = putValuesInArray(mapObject(notifications, (email, matches) => {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        //console.log(matches);
        let template_object = {
            showHeader: true,
            date: moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY'),
            categories: []
        };

        mapObject(matches, (keyword, tweets) => {
            template_object.categories.push({
                name: keyword,
                tweets: tweets.map( (tweet) => {
                    return {
                        authorImage: tweet.user.profile_image_url_https.replace('_normal','_bigger'),
                        authorName: tweet.user.name,
                        authorLink: 'https://twitter.com/'+tweet.user.screen_name,
                        authorScreenname: tweet.user.screen_name,
                        tweetText: tweet.text,
                        tweetLink: 'https://twitter.com/'+tweet.user.screen_name+'/status/'+tweet.id_str
                    };
                })
            });
        });

        let html = emailTemplate(template_object);

        mandrill.messages.send({
            message: {
                to: [{
                    email: email
                }],
                from_email: 'support@prhunters.com',
                from_name: 'PR Hunters',
                subject: "Daily PR Opportunities",
                html,
                tags: ["tweet_notification"],
                track_opens: true,
                auto_html: true,
                preserve_recipients: false
            }
        },function(result){
            console.log('email sent!',result);
            if(result[0].status === "rejected" || result[0].status === "invalid"){
                reject("Error sending email: "+result[0].reject_reason);
            }
            resolve(result);
        },function(error){
            console.error('error sending email',error);
            reject(error);
        });
    });
}));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the bit that sends the email is ...

```
mandrill.messages.send
```

so you just need to wrap that code in an IF condition.

```
if (number of tweets>0) {
     mandrill.messages.send
}
```

You just need to determine the correct condition to work out whether the number of tweets is greater than 0.

look at the template_object and compare when there are none versus when there are some matches and use that to determine the relevant condition.